# Jquery apply callback on OnChange event which call api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Hi i'm trying to apply a callback to use on my dynamic select boxes instead of TimeOut

Currently i have 4 select options boxes(3 are dynamic options): City, District(options based on city options), Ward(options based on district options) and Street(options based on district options)

It's a search form so the next page form should has the previous form values, i use Django to determined if a previous form values are select , then if so it will add a hidden div with id="value-filter" in the template. And now i use the Jquery to check if that div exists to change the select options

If a user click on the city option then it will activate the city onchange event to call an api that populate District options with the corresponding city Id, Ward and Street options are the same but based on District options to call their api in order to populate their options.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //call district api if city option is selected
  $('select#city').change(function(event) {
    $.getJSON("/api_get_districts/", {
      id: $(this).val()
    }, function(j) {
      var options = '<option selected disabled>-- District --</option>';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#district").html(options);
    });
  });
  //call ward and street api if district option is selected
  $('select#district').change(function(event) {
    $.getJSON("/api_get_wards/", {
      id: $(this).val()
    }, function(j) {
      var options = '<option selected disabled>-- Ward --</option>';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#ward").html(options);
    });
    $.getJSON("/api_get_streets/", {
      id: $(this).val()
    }, function(j) {
      var options = '<option selected disabled>-- Street --</option>';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#street").html(options);
    });
  });
  // main one to handle select option if the div of a values is present in html
  if ($('#district-filter').length) {
    $('select#city').val("{{ filter_form_values.city |safe }}").change();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('select#district').val("{{ filter_form_values.district |safe }}").change();
      if ($('#ward-filter').length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('select#ward').val("{{ filter_form_values.ward |safe }}").change();
        }, 500);
      }
      if ($('#street-filter').length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('select#street').val("{{ filter_form_values.street |safe }}").change();
        }, 500);
      }
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Tỉnh </label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="city" id="city" required="">
    <option selected="" disabled="">-- City --</option>

    <option value="1">Hà Nội</option>

    <option value="2">Hồ Chí Minh</option>

    <option value="3">Bình Dương</option>

    <option value="4">Đà Nẵng</option>

    <option value="5">Hải Phòng</option>

    <option value="6">Long An</option>

    <option value="7">Bà Rịa Vũng Tàu</option>

    <option value="8">An Giang</option>

    <option value="9">Bắc Giang</option>

    <option value="10">Bắc Kạn</option>

    <option value="11">Bạc Liêu</option>

    <option value="12">Bắc Ninh</option>

    <option value="13">Bến Tre</option>

    <option value="14">Bình Định</option>

    <option value="15">Bình Phước</option>

    <option value="16">Bình Thuận</option>

    <option value="17">Cà Mau</option>

    <option value="18">Cần Thơ</option>

    <option value="19">Cao Bằng</option>

    <option value="20">Đắk Lắk</option>

    <option value="21">Đắk Nông</option>

    <option value="22">Điện Biên</option>

    <option value="23">Đồng Nai</option>

    <option value="24">Đồng Tháp</option>

    <option value="25">Gia Lai</option>

    <option value="26">Hà Giang</option>

    <option value="27">Hà Nam</option>

    <option value="28">Hà Tĩnh</option>

    <option value="29">Hải Dương</option>

    <option value="30">Hậu Giang</option>

    <option value="31">Hòa Bình</option>

    <option value="32">Hưng Yên</option>

    <option value="33">Khánh Hòa</option>

    <option value="34">Kiên Giang</option>

    <option value="35">Kon Tum</option>

    <option value="36">Lai Châu</option>

    <option value="37">Lâm Đồng</option>

    <option value="38">Lạng Sơn</option>

    <option value="39">Lào Cai</option>

    <option value="40">Nam Định</option>

    <option value="41">Nghệ An</option>

    <option value="42">Ninh Bình</option>

    <option value="43">Ninh Thuận</option>

    <option value="44">Phú Thọ</option>

    <option value="45">Phú Yên</option>

    <option value="46">Quảng Bình</option>

    <option value="47">Quảng Nam</option>

    <option value="48">Quảng Ngãi</option>

    <option value="49">Quảng Ninh</option>

    <option value="50">Quảng Trị</option>

    <option value="51">Sóc Trăng</option>

    <option value="52">Sơn La</option>

    <option value="53">Tây Ninh</option>

    <option value="54">Thái Bình</option>

    <option value="55">Thái Nguyên</option>

    <option value="56">Thanh Hóa</option>

    <option value="57">Thừa Thiên Huế</option>

    <option value="58">Tiền Giang</option>

    <option value="59">Trà Vinh</option>

    <option value="60">Tuyên Quang</option>

    <option value="61">Vĩnh Long</option>

    <option value="62">Vĩnh Phúc</option>

    <option value="63">Yên Bái</option>

  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>District </label>
  <div id="district-filter" style="display: none"></div>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="district" id="district">
    <option selected="" disabled="">-- District --</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Ward </label>
  <div id="ward-filter" style="display: none"></div>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="ward" id="ward">
    <option selected="" disabled="">-- Ward --</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Street </label>
  <div id="street-filter" style="display: none"></div>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="street" id="street">
    <option selected="" disabled="">-- Street --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Everything worked great but now i want to try to change my timeOut function in the if ($('#district-filter').length) {} to a callback. I had tried the following by using when() to apply callback:

```
if ($('#district-filter').length) {
    $.when($('select#city').val("{{ filter_form_values.city |safe }}").change()).then(function() {
        $.when($('select#district').val("{{ filter_form_values.district |safe }}").change()).then(function() {
            if ($('#ward-filter').length) {
                $('select#ward').val("{{ filter_form_values.ward |safe }}").change();
            }
            if ($('#street-filter').length) {
                $('select#street').val("{{ filter_form_values.street |safe }}").change();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

On page load the city is select and the District load but the district options didn't get select so the Ward and Street options also empty.

How do i use callback to wait for my Api to populate an options then select that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had decided to just use normal callback and add the request api function in the check:

```
if ($('#city-filter').length) {
    $('select#city').val("{{ filter_form_values.city |safe }}").change();
}
if ($('#district-filter').length || $('#ward-filter').length || $('#street-filter').length) {
    $.getJSON("/api_get_district/", {
        id: "{{ filter_form_values.city |safe }}"
    }, function(j) {
        var options = '<option selected disabled>-- District --</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#district").html(options);
        $('select#district').val("{{ filter_form_values.district |safe }}").change();
        if ($('#ward-filter').length) {
            $.getJSON("/api_get_ward/", {
                id: "{{ filter_form_values.district |safe }}"
            }, function(j) {
                var options = '<option selected disabled>-- Ward --</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
                }
                $("select#ward").html(options);
                $('select#ward').val("{{ filter_form_values.ward |safe }}").change();
            });
        }
        if ($('#street-filter').length) {
            $.getJSON("/api_get_street/", {
                id: "{{ filter_form_values.district |safe }}"
            }, function(j) {
                var options = '<option selected disabled>-- Street --</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
                }
                $("select#street").html(options);
                $('select#street').val("{{ filter_form_values.street |safe }}").change();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

also add city check to the html:

```
<div id="city-filter" style="display: none"></div>
```

And now it worked but i will take any suggestion to improve it as answer(since calling api 2 times isn't consider a good idea)!